# get a value and insert the increment of that value in sql server

Tags: sql-server

I Have  a table in SQL SERver with name T_ACCOUNT with 2 columns ACCOUNT_ID and CUSTOMER_ID both as int.
Now i have to read the last row of that table and insert a new row with the values of last row incrementing by 1.
How can I do this?

I tried like this

```
SELECT ACCOUNT_ID,CUSTOMER_ID FROM T_ACCOUNT order by ACCOUNT_ID desc
INSERT T_ACCOUNT(ACCOUNT_ID,CUSTOMER_ID)
VALUES(ACCOUNT_ID = ACCOUNT_ID + 1 AND CUSTOMER_ID = CUSTOMER_ID +1)
```

but it was showing the syntax error.can anyone help me

Comment: What does MySQL have to do with this question?

Comment: That is just for a broad audience... like Twitter.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The below statement picks the last row (record with max account_id) and inserts the next row.

```
INSERT INTO  T_ACCOUNT (ACCOUNT_ID,CUSTOMER_ID)
SELECT ACCOUNT_ID + 1, CUSTOMER_ID +1 
FROM T_ACCOUNT
Where ACCOUNT_ID = (select max(ACCOUNT_ID) from T_ACCOUNT)
```

The where clause is used in picking the last row.

Comment: @sindhujampani you could accept the answer if the solution worked for you.

Answer (score 0):

A very strange requirement but anyway this is how you would go about doing this....

```
INSERT INTO  T_ACCOUNT (ACCOUNT_ID,CUSTOMER_ID)
SELECT TOP 1 ACCOUNT_ID + 1, CUSTOMER_ID +1 
FROM T_ACCOUNT
ORDER BY  ACCOUNT_ID desc
```

Order by is irrelevant here, no need for that.

You should really create a stored procedure to do this operation, Create two `output` parameters to get the newly created values. something like as follows

```
CREATE PROCEDURE dbo.Add_Record
@ACCOUNT_ID   INT OUTPUT,
@CUSTOMER_ID  INT OUTPUT
AS
BEGIN
 SET NOCOUNT ON;
  DECLARE @AccountID INT, @CustomerID INT;

  SELECT TOP 1  @AccountID   = ACCOUNT_ID
               ,@CUSTOMER_ID = CUSTOMER_ID
  FROM T_ACCOUNT
  ORDER BY ACCOUNT_ID DESC;

  SET @AccountID   = @AccountID + 1;
  SET @CUSTOMER_ID = @CUSTOMER_ID + 1;

  INSERT INTO T_ACCOUNT (ACCOUNT_ID,CUSTOMER_ID)
  VALUES (@AccountID, @CUSTOMER_ID)

END
```

Comment: No. OP wants to read the latest and use them to insert next. Your answer selects all and *may* cause an index error. And hence is wrong.

Comment: It was throwing an error.Violation of PRIMARY KEY constraint 'PK_T_ACCOUNT'. Cannot insert duplicate key in object 'dbo.T_ACCOUNT'. The duplicate key value is (360).

Answer (score 0):

You should consider creating a column in your sql table that auto increments so you can just do an insert at end of existing records.